# Синтаксис для одновременного использования выражения 'If/While' и derived tables (subqueries) в sql/mssql/t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет!

Никак не могу найти в гугле:
 Как можно комбинировать выражение 'If begin ... end'/'While begin ... end' с использованием подзапросов?

Цель: с некоторыми подзапросами при разных условиях нужно делать разные вещи. Если бы это нужно было делать один раз, то я бы не мучилась, но подобная операция повторяется 20 млн раз = 'кол-во юзеров'*'кол-во операций для каждого юзера.

Поскольку каждый раз - это достаточно маленькая порция данных, то, после прочтения разных блогов и ссылок, поняла, что нужно попробовать именно SubQueries, которые хранятся в памяти базы, а не записываются на жесткий диск (в отличие от #tempTables и @tableVariables). Должно быть, по идее, эффективней и быстрей для 20 млн операций, но у меня синтаксис не получается написать.

Например, вот этот не работает. Говорит, что ошибка около слова 'While'.
Быть может, кто-нибудь знает как правильно это делать (использовать вместе While/If и subqueries) и можно ли делать так вообще?

Буду очень благодарна за подсказку!

```
With TA_temp_user_id_BCD as 
(select  * 
from Analysis.dbo.TA_temp_FoFosFr_2 as t
where t.User_GK = @user_id_num__  and t.Flag_Category = 0
)

------
------  
----------------------------------
while (@control_date__ > @registration_datetime__) and (@epoche_num__ <= @epoches_MAX__)
begin
declare @modal_tariff__ nvarchar(100) = dbo.Modal_Tariff(@user_id_num__, @control_date__)
--With--??--
TA_temp_user_id_row as
(   
        select   User_id                                                            as User_id
            ,avg(Customer_Total_Cost*1.0)                                       as UserBill_AVG                                     
            ,max(Number_of_Attempts)                                                    as Number_of_Attempts_MAX
            ,avg(Session_Duration*1.0)                                                  as BCD_Session_Duration_AVG                                                                                             
            ,@modal_tariff__ as BCD_Modal_Tariff
            ,@epoche_num__  as Epoche_Num
            ,@control_date__ as Control_Datetime
        from @TA_temp_user_id
        where Start_Datetime <= @control_date__
        group by User_id
        )
        --------------------------------------
                    if (@step__ = 0 and @epoche_num__ = 0)
                        begin
                            select *  
                            into Analysis.dbo.TA_temp_Features_BCD_New_SubQ
                            from TA_temp_user_id_row
                        end
                    else 
                            insert into Analysis.dbo.TA_temp_Features_BCD_New_SubQ  
                            select *  
                            from TA_temp_user_id_row;

      ------------------------------------------

    set @control_date__  = dateadd(day, - @x_period__, @control_date__);
    set @epoche_num__    = @epoche_num__ + 1;

end;
```

Comment: никак. управляющие конструкции вида `while` и `if` к подзапросам вообще не относятся, это элементы языка TSQL.
у вас в коде идет CTE а потом цикл. Тут два варианта, либо сделать исходный запрос вместо CTE, затем к нему курсор, и перебирать дальше строки в цикле while,
Либо после CTE должна идти инструкция select, либо следующий CTE.

Я что то тут вообще не вижу связи между первым CTE и дальнейшим while.

Comment: то есть в данном случае ругается на while, т.к. после CTE должен идти другой CTE или запрос к нему.

Comment: О, спасибо. Не знала этих тонкостей про TSQL и CTE. Попробую с курсором идею.